# Track down where content comes from

Tags: joomla2.5

Being new to Joomla I do not know all the tricks for troubleshooting etc. Currently I have a page that has a section of content on it. The content is created by DT Register but I've been through the CP several times and cannot find the section?

I hope someone is up and can share with me how to track down where pieces of content come from so I can find where this is being generated and change as needed.

The page in question is a DT Register form. I can locate and modify every section of the page EXCEPT one.

The section is titled USER INFORMATION and captures userid & password to create an account. Looking at the element in developer tools it would appear it is part of the dt register generated code but as I mentioned I can't find it.

The sandbox I am playing in is here:  http://take7.lamplighterguild.com/index.php/register?eventId=15&controller=event&task=individualRegister

The section is towards the top and is hard to read on the page...which is why I want to find it.

Thank you for any help or direction.

---

So unfortunately my question was poorly worded. I have no trouble at all getting the css changed. It is the origin of the content that I am really trying to track down. Where does it come from etc. Is there a way to detect if it came from an article, or a component, etc. I thought there might be clues as how to figure that out.

Comment: Please see my latest edit

Answer (score 0):

For troubleshooting issues like this, tools like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) or Web Inspector for Chrome and Safari are your go to tools. If you aren't already familiar with them you'll find lots of help online.

There is default body text styling of colour #D9A362 getting into your page from one of the stylesheets. I can't find the source quickly myself, though it's easy enough to write an override.

One place you could do this is open http://take7.lamplighterguild.com/templates/theme1001/css/template.css with a text editor. Below the existing body rule @ line 7, add something like

```
body.cssstyle-style1{
color:black;
}
```

This will fix the H2 text at the top of the page which you mention, plus the 'user information' line immeadiately above the form.

Hope this helps!

EDIT
You have something which is writing the following style to your page head and this is the culprit:

```
body {font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px; line-height:21px; color:#D9A362; }
```

It's even on your home page so it's not necesaarily related to DT Register. To me it looks like it's coming from your menu extension.